# When create function in SQL, Scalar variable must be INT?

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions, scalar

```
CREATE FUNCTION show_inst_borrowed_out(@bRecordID CHAR(10))
RETURN TABLE
AS
RETURN
(SELECT bRecordID, br.instID, g,instType
FROM borrowRecord br
INNER JOIN gear g ON br.instID = g.instID
WHERE bRecordID = @bRecordID);

SELECT * FROM show_inst_borrowed_out(BR00000004);
```

When I run the above statement, it shows this:

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 416
Invalid column name 'BR00000004'.

What should I type if my scalar variable will be something like BR00000004 [CHAR(10)]?

Comment: Which DBMS is this in? MySQL? MS SQL Server? PostgreSQL? Oracle? Please **[edit]** your question and add the DBMS in use with a tag. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be

```
SELECT * FROM show_inst_borrowed_out('BR00000004')
```

Since you declared it as CHAR, you have to enclose it in apostrophes.

Comment: Thank you for the help!!